# Install windows on formatted dynamic disk without installation CD/DVD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, partitioning

Here's what happened:

I had been running Windows 7 with "maximum number of partitions" in Windows. Checked with disk manager.

I converted disk to dynamic disk and created a partition.

I run a bootable pendrive (DVD is not supported) and start installing Windows 7. During setup it shows Windows can't be installed on this partition so I start formatting partition from there. I removed all partitions, even system and recovery. This was apparently a big mistake.

Now when I try to start BOOTMGR is not found.

1. I tried installing again, but it showed error in loading `system32/winload.exe` and asked to insert my installation media, unfortunately DVD is not supported.
2. I tried network boot using Serva but during setup I don't see any drives it asks to load driver. And there is no repair your computer option in during setup.

   - I downloaded SATA drivers but no success even when I load drivers during installation.
   - I don't know how to bring back Repair Your Computer option.
3. Linux can't touch the dynamic disk, I heard
4. Windows 7 live cd gave me the last hope, but it failed two times and it takes like 6 hours to setup. It fails by restarting and asking start Windows normally screen? I start it, then comes setup is loading services, then it says installation error  reinstall. *maybe something can be done here*

## Possible solutions:

1. Is there any small live CD options, Microsoft-Dos or XP or Windows 7 with diskpart functionality?
2. Any way bring back repair your computer when doing a network boot?
3. Any way to completely format hard disk so I can have a basic disk in which Windows can be installed over network boot or a bootable flash drive?

I am just a student who only knew how to install Windows using setup, so believe me I have tried everything I can think off, every site I can visit and now only you guys can  me.

Last option for me is to take harddisk out and put it in my pc and do a format, don't know how to do that, though.

PS. I have another acer laptop and a desktop pc both with Windows 10.
PPS. I can't download more than 500 MB unless extremely necessary.

Laptop specs:

- Sony Vaio PCG-61113P
- Intel core 2 duo inside
- Came with Windows 7

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I took out the laptop hard disk and connected it to my pc. Now formatting and installing windows 7. thanks anyways to the community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On [Serva](http://vercot.com/~serva/an/WindowsPXE1.html#troubleshooting)'s Windows Application Note read:

```
8.8- Troubleshooting WDS OSs missing "Repair your computer" link

The link "Repair your computer" is missing. This is because of a bug within
autorun.dll (one of Setup.exe components) which mistakenly checks for the 
availability of the Recovery Environment based on the current directory 
(GetFullPathName()) instead of parsing the %systemdrive% variable. While 
this error passes totally unnoticed when installing from DVD it presents 
the missing link problem when Setup.exe is run from a network location.


In order to regain the access to the Recovery Environment if needed we can 
create RecEnv.bat i.e.

C:\SERVA_REPO\WIA_WDS\Vista32\sources\RecEnv.bat

RecEnv.bat

   @ECHO OFF
   cd /d %systemdrive%\sources\recovery
   RecEnv.exe 

Then when we reach the "Install Now" screen on W8/7 or the one after on 
Vista, we open a console windows with Shift+F10 and just run RecEnv.
```

If you are using a retail or MSDN Windows 7 ISO as your source surely you'll be able to get the missing `Repair your computer` link when PXE booting the client.